# Install Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Sharepoint Services 1.3 on XP

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to setup an enviroment to develop in SharePoint.
I have XP with Visual Studio 2008 Profesional, on XP I have a virtual Windows Server 2003 where I install Share Point Services 3.0.

On XP I want to install Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Sharepoint Services 1.3, I have already modified the registry like http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/how-to-install-the-sharepoint-2007-vs-2005-extensions-on-a-workstation/ mention.

But when I try to run the set up I received the following error [image]

I google for this error and found that I must install it using the msiexec /i option, but the error continues.

My question is can I install this on an xp machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP isn't supported.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FB9D4B85-DA2A-432E-91FB-D505199C49F6&displaylang=en

You'll have to setup a VM to do SharePoint development on XP.

Now if you're adventurous you can try this:
http://mkdot.net/blogs/zzl/archive/2008/06/18/install-vs-2005-2008-extensions-for-sharepoint-on-windows-xp-vista-os.aspx

I'd recommend a server 2003/2008 VM for SharePoint development though.